# How do I get a value from a listbox instead of a textbox, my code is as follows

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZurG.png)I'm trying to make a program that shows the prime numbers of the numbers added to the listbox from the textbox and then written in the listbox, with a message box, can anyone help me, where am I wrong?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    int deneme = 0;
    int sayilarim = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    for (int i = 2; i < sayilarim; i++) {
        if (sayilarim % i == 0)
            deneme++;
        }
        if (deneme != 0){                       
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + " Asal Sayi değildir.");
            MessageBox.Show("Bu Bir Asal Sayi Değildir.");
        } else {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + " sayidir.");
            MessageBox.Show("Bu Bir Asal Sayi.");
        }
        textBox1.Clear();
    }                
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " Adet asal sayı var.");
```

Comment: please don't tag irrelevant languages to get more attention. it will only attract downvotes.

Comment: I am currently writing a number in the textbox, for example, 10 15 16 17 etc. I add them to the listbox, then find the prime numbers, so when I press button 2, I want it to show the prime numbers in the listbox with the messagebox.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? Why you have `textBox1.Clear();` inside for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your button2 is not getting value of Listbox1 ,
it takes value of textbox.
you have to take items of Listbox1 and put them in a list or etc.
and make your algorithm for them.
here is some sample code.

öncelikle buton 2 nin altında sayıları listbox içinden değil textbox'tan almışsın, onu düzeltmen gerek. listenin elemanlarında dönüp int bir listeye atama yapabilirsin. Bu adımları düzenledikten sonra altta verdiğim örnek kodu bir dene bakalım,

```
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("Asal Olan Sayilar:");
               
            List<int> lst = new List<int>(); // {  3, 4, 5, 10 };
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString()));
            }
          
    
                bool asalMi = true;
                foreach (int value in lst)
                {
                    asalMi = true;
                    for (int i = 2; i < value; i++)
                    {
                        if (value % i == 0)
                        {
                            asalMi = false;
                        }
                    }
    
                    if (asalMi)
                        str.AppendLine($"{value.ToString()} asaldir.");
                }
    
                MessageBox.Show(str.ToString);
```

Comment: 1 bağımsız değişkeni : yöntem grubu öğesinden string öğesine dönüştürülemiyor diyor sondaki str.tostring den dolayı

Comment: kod düzgün çalışıyor görseli ekliyorum (https://ibb.co/wKSfk3T).
 hata aldığın yapıyı tümden gösterebilirsen yardımcı olmaya çalışırım.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/2341wty

Comment: cevaptaki kodu listenin elemanlarini int e cevirip yeni listeye ekleyecek sekilde duzenledim. Listbox a sadece sayilari eklediginden emin olmak lazim tabi.

attigin link acilmiyor.

Comment: onu dümdüz button a yapıştırdım fakat bunu yapınca str.tostring kısmında hata veriyor

Comment: Önem Derecesi Kod Açıklama Proje Dosya Çizgi Gizleme Durumu
Hata CS1503 1 bağımsız değişkeni: 'yöntem grubu' öğesinden 'string' öğesine dönüştürülemiyor

Comment: str.AppendLine($"{value.ToString()} asaldir.");      olacak .

Comment: }
                    MessageBox.Show(str.ToString);
                }
            }
        } bu kısım efendim

Comment: // {  3, 4, 5, 10 };
yazan kısma ne yapacağımı anlayamadım tam olarak.

Comment: orasi Örnek liste elemanlarıydı.
stringBuilder yerine string'te kullanabilirsin ;

string str = "";
            str += "Asal Olan Sayilar:";
str += $"{value} asaldir.";   şeklinde düzenleyebilirsin.  Gönderdiğin hata mesajları türkçe olduğundan anlamadım hatayı neden veriyor.  tahminen Stringbuilder 'i toString edemiyordu neyse string deneyebilirsin.